# Cocos2d CCScale

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to create pulsing platforms and have some problems with CCScale.
I have some objects of my Platforms class in NSMuttableArray.

```
@interface Platforms : CCNode{

    CCSprite *platformSprite;
    int typeP;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *platformSprite;
@property int typeP;
```

@implementation

```
- (id)init:(int)type
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        typeP = type;
        platformSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ball.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 51, 52)];
        [self addChild:platformSprite];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I added all objects to screen

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < [_array count]; i++) {
        Platforms* _platforms2 = [[_array objectAtIndex:i ]retain];
        [self addChild:_platforms2];
        [_platforms2 release];
}
```

So ... i want to get all objects where typeP == 1
i get all this objects and add them to NSMuttableArray

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < [platformsArrayOnScreen count]; i++) {
        Platforms* temp = [platformsArrayOnScreen objectAtIndex:i];
        if (temp.typeP == 1) {
            [scaleArray addObject:temp];
}
```

Than i want to scale all of them to `[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scale:0.2f];`
and after that scale to `[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scale:1.0f];`

i created function `[self schedule:@selector(checkForScale:)];`

```
-(void)checkForScale:(ccTime)dt {

    for (int i = 0; i < [scaleArray count]; i++) {
        Platforms* temp2 = [scaleArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([temp2.platformSprite scale] == 1.0f) {
            [self scaleDown:temp2];
        }
        if([temp2.platformSprite scale] == 0.2f){
            [self scaleUp:temp2];
        }
    }
}

-(void)scaleDown:(Platforms *)tempSprite {

    id scaleDown = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.3 scaleX:0.2f scaleY:0.2f];
    [tempSprite.platformSprite runAction:scaleDown];

}
-(void)scaleUp:(Platforms *)tempSprite {

    id scaleUp = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.3 scaleX:1.0f scaleY:1.0f];
    [tempSprite runAction:scaleUp];

}
```

But it's don't work (( my platforms don't pulsing. Where is my problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Are scaleUp/scaleDown called? You should set a breakpoint there and find out. The only thing I can imagine is that equality with floating point values is tricky. Ie the scale property may not be exactly 0.2f but 0.199999999f or 0.200000001f

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do this you can CCSequence.

```
[tempSprite.platformSprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:3.0f scale:0.2f],[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:3.0f scale:1.0f], nil]];
```

Need not to do all this :

```
-(void)checkForScale:(ccTime)dt 
-(void)scaleDown:(Platforms *)tempSprite 
-(void)scaleUp:(Platforms *)tempSprite
```